# How to store long expression in separate file?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm building a Vue app where a user reactively generates an HTML page from certain selections. Therefore, there is a very long expression that produces said HTML page. This expression/template is stored in a separate `.html` file. I would like to have that expression as a computed property in my app, but not sure what's the best way. I want to be able to use either the `{{ }}` template syntax, or at least the syntax you get inside directives, rather than have to plaster `this.` in front of every property and method I use, which is what I'd have to do if I move the template to JS-land (e.g. a separate module or just directly define it in the computed property).

Right now I got it working, but it's extremely hacky:

```js
let appSpec = {
    /* [snip] */
    computed: {
        /* other computed properties and… */
        html () {
            return getAppHTML(this);
        }
    },
};
let sheetTemplate = await (await fetch("sheet-template.html")).text();
let templateVars = [
    ...Object.keys(INITIAL_DATA), 
    ...Object.keys(appSpec.computed), 
    ...Object.keys(appSpec.methods)
];
let getAppHTML = new Function(`{${ templateVars.join(", ") }}`, "return `" + sheetTemplate + "`");

/* ... */
```

I’m thinking there *must* be a better way to do this.

I don't want to inject the expression directly into the places it's going to be used in my app (e.g. `<iframe :srcdoc>`), because I want to have a property that corresponds to it (for watchers etc).

Note that I'm using the in-browser API, no build step, and I'd rather keep it that way.

Comment: Eval is evil. It should be used as the last resort in such cases.  You can use Vue's own runtime template compiler or some third-party solution if it doesn't suit you

Comment: A 'hacky' disclaimer doesn't mean that you understand its potential hazard. It's unknown if a user can be trusted in your case. Generally it should be avoided at all cost. As for a compiler, just define a component dynamically like usual `{ template: ... }` and render it with <component :is> https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components . The use of `template` string without using SFC requires to use Vue build that includes a compiler (you'll be notified with an error otherwise), but that's all

Comment: I don't want to render it, I want to stuff it into a property to be used in attributes etc. So I'm still not quite sure if what you're suggesting solves my problem. For context, I'm very very new to Vue (so nothing is "like usual" lol), but have been writing JS for almost two decades.

Comment: You need to render a component in order to have html. I assume that's the role of getAppHTML. It's unclear how exactly you use it

Comment: getAppHTML() returns a string of HTML, that is then used in a computed property (html, shown above). The computed property is used in <iframe srcdoc> (well, actually a web component that does something similar) as well as a <code> element. It is not rendered directly in the same page as the app. The purpose of the app is to *produce* other apps, so that HTML is output, not UI.

Comment: Then you need to render dynamic component to some dummy DOM element and get its innerHTML, as it was suggested

Comment: I don't want to render this HTML in my main app, that could have unintended side effects and seems like an even worse solution than using eval(). Surely there must be a way to access Vue's template compiler directly rather than doing roundabout hacks?

Comment: My suggestion was to just render it, likely as new createApp , on dummy DOM element that is detached from the rest of elements. What kind of effects? If you have a component that was specifically designed for this purpose, I don't see problems. Otherwise the problem is you try to render to static HTML something that has side effects and isn't supposed to be static, it may just not work properly in a frame.

Comment: I.e. `let dynRoot = document.createElement('div'); createApp({ template: dynStr, data() {...}).mount(dynRoot); dynHtml = dynRoot.innerHTML`